# Loading local css & js files into WKWebView

Tags: swift2, wkwebview, xcode7.1

in Swift 2.1.1 & Xcode 7.1
My code uses WKWebView and loads index.html form a local file but fails to load index.css and other javascript files as shown in the head tag.

My best guess is that the baseURL is not correct, if so, How can I set the baseURL correctly? Thanks

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView! = nil  //allows the class to refrence WKWebView
var webView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.webView = WKWebView()
    self.view = self.webView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let HTMLDocumentPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")
    let HTMLString: NSString?

    do {
        HTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: HTMLDocumentPath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let baseUrl  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("")
        webView!.loadHTMLString(HTMLString as! String, baseURL: baseUrl)

    } catch {
        HTMLString = nil
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

```html
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>RRR</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
   </head>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of reading [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html) about the file url I was able to solve the problem.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView! = nil  //allows the class to reference WKWebView
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let baseUrl = NSURL(string: "file:///<yourFilePath>/abc/")
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("abc/index", ofType: "html")
        let HTMLString: NSString?

        do {
            HTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            webView!.loadHTMLString(HTMLString as! String, baseURL: baseUrl )

        } catch {
            HTMLString = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please describe exactly what path you used instead of `file:///<yourFilePath>/abc/`? Thanks

Comment: It's important that your baseUrl begins with 'file://', the exact filePath isn't that important

Comment: Bundle.main.bundlePath (Swift 3)